# Change name of subfolder and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, server

I have some links like this:

```
http://example.com/firstfolder/oldfolder/file1.html
http://example.com/firstfolder/oldfolder/file2.html
http://example.com/firstfolder/oldfolder/file3.html
http://example.com/firstfolder/oldfolder/file4.html
```

Now, the `oldfolder`s name has changed to `newfolder`.

I want to rewrite and redirect all `oldfolder` to `newfolder`.

Means, if you open e.g.

`http://example.com/firstfolder/oldfolder/file3.html`

it should redirect to

`http://example.com/firstfolder/newfolder/file3.html`

I tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^oldfolder/(.*) /newfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Unfortunately this is doing nothing. There's no redirect. It's the same as before.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Redirect` directive to redirect your old folder uris to the new one :

```
Redirect 301 /firstfolder/oldfolder/ http://example.com/firstfolder/newfolder/
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it odd that there is a "."in your url.

Otherwise in the htaccess you can try to add a "\" like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^old\.folder/(.*) /newfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: For some reason, this is not working for me, even if I test with a link without a dot in it.

Comment: And directly with the complete URL like that : Redirect 301 /firstfolder/oldfolder/file1.html http://example.com/firstfolder/newfolder/file1.html

Comment: That gives an `Internal Server Error` for my website. But this is working: `Redirect 301 /firstfolder/oldfolder/file1.html /firstfolder/newfolder/file1.html`

But I would prefer not to make a single command for every file.

Comment: And like this : RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^firstfolder/oldfolder/(.*) firstfolder/newfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]